# VS2013 Premium Edition is equivalent to VS2015 which edition?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, msdn

We are having Visual Studio Premium edition 2013 in our machine.

We are planning to upgrade to VS2015 which is having GIT source control integration.

Can some one please suggest which edition of VS2015 is equivalent to VS2013 Premium Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Visual Studio 2013 Premium and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate were merged and replaced by Visual Studio 2015 *Enterprise*.

For MSDN subscriptions this meant that if you had VS Premium with MSDN or VS Ultimate with MSDN before, you were automatically upgraded to VS Enterprise with MSDN.